# Can I force the XSLT collection function to treat all files as XSL?

Tags: xslt, collections, saxon

I'm currently building an XSLT stylesheet used to document other XSLT stylesheets in a series of folders and sub-folders. My code pulls out specific details about variables, functions, etc and renders it in an output format. The sheets being read are created by a 3rd party product. Most of them have an XSL extension but some of them are proprietary extensions. I have some files with a DTCBS extension but they are just XSL stylesheets.

I'm currently loading the content of these files into a variable using the XSLT function "collection" as follows:

`<xsl:variable name="Collection" select="collection(concat('file:///', encode-for-uri(replace($filePath, '\\', '/')),'?select=*.(xsl|dtcbs|xml);recurse=yes'))" as="node()*"/>`

The variable works just fine if I use XSL|XML. But if I include the DTCBS extension, the variable blows up citing "the supplied value is xs:base64Binary".

If I manually put the xml declaration line at the top of my DTCBS file, the variable works fine. Those DTCBS files are auto-generated without the declaration line so I can't fix that, nor can I manually edit them each time I want to run my documenter code.

From what I can tell, because it's not an XSL extension, and the XML declaration line isn't present, the XSLT parser thinks it's base64 when it isn't.

I'm using Saxon as my XSLT parser and the [Saxon documentation](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/sourcedocs/collections.html) says it uses file extensions and http headers to detect the file type.

Does anyone know if there is a way to **force** collection() to treat every file as an XSL?

Tried adding the XML declaration line in the DTCBS file. This did correct the issue but I can't do this in all cases as I am trying to automate the entire thing.

I also renamed the DTCBS extension to XSL and the problem went away as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add e.g. `content-type=application/xml` e.g. `'?select=*.(xsl|dtcbs|xml);recurse=yes;content-type=application/xml'`.

Comment: Good suggestion but it looks like the Saxon parser doesn't recognize the content-type as a valid parameter on the request.

Comment: It is documented for Saxon 11 which is the current stable release so if you can try that release.

Comment: Saxon 10 and later should support it.

Comment: Indeed it does. I switched my version to Saxon 10 and it worked like a charm. 

Thank you VERY much for this!

Answer (score 1):

As well as Martin's suggestion, you can register content types with the Saxon configuration:

```
processor.getUnderlyingConfiguration()
    .registerFileExtension("dtcbs", "application/xml");
```

This has been available since Saxon 9.7.